# testng multiple threads for whole IT class

Tags: java, multithreading, testing, testng

i have a testng suite with some 2 test methods. createuser() and updateuser(). also i have an instance variable User user;
so at end of createUser() i associate the created user to that instance variable user. now in updateUSer() (dependent upon Createuser) i try to update some attributes of this object.

everything runs fine normally. but when i use invocationcount=3, threadpoolsize=3, sometimes some of the methods will fail. now i figured out this is due to 1 common shared User instance for different threads.

is there any way  whole IT class with different methods run in 1 single thread but i can spawn multiple executions of this IT.
so thread 1 -> IT with 2 tests, thread 2-> IT with 2 tests and so on...

so i am looking something like invocationcount and threadpoolsize for the whole IT class instead of each method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used ExecutorService to manually run TestNG tests in different threads.